# What is the correct starting xaml for a file that will eventually become a repository for styles

Tags: wpf

As I gradually begin to understand a little more about wpf's styles and data templates and how they can be reused So the sense of having a separate project with various stles and templates defined therein and referenced as a merged dictionary in the application(s) that need to use them makes sense.

I have looked at several posts here and on code project.  One particular one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249492/how-to-organize-resources-styles-in-a-complex-wpf-scenario) makes a great deal of sense, but every article I've looked at appears to omit one small point.

Lets say that I have a style defined like so:

```
<Style TargetType="dxb:BarButtonItem"
           x:Key="NewStBtnStyle">
        <Setter Property="SuperTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <dx:SuperTip>
                    <dx:SuperTipHeaderItem Content="New" />
                    <dx:SuperTipItem Content="Create a new record"
                                     Glyph="pack://application:,,,/FishTrackerProfessional;component/Resources/Images/32/New.png">
                        <dx:SuperTipItem.LayoutStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type dx:Items2Panel}">
                                <Setter Property="Alignment"
                                        Value="Right" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalIndent"
                                        Value="20" />
                            </Style>
                        </dx:SuperTipItem.LayoutStyle>
                    </dx:SuperTipItem>
                    <dx:SuperTipItemSeparator />
                    <dx:SuperTipItem Content="Opens a new record entry form in a new window">
                        <dx:SuperTipItem.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri"
                                           Foreground="Gray"
                                           FontSize="11"
                                           Text="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </dx:SuperTipItem.ContentTemplate>
                    </dx:SuperTipItem>
                </dx:SuperTip>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I can see that it will be useful, not just in one project but in several, and more so with a little adaptation It can be modified to produce similar sytles for different similar items.

Now my question is this.  I want to put a group of styles into a single file (myNewStyles.xaml).  I'm familirar with a window beging

```
<window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

or a user control beginning

```
<userControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

I had thought that the following would be the correct syntax to begin a xaml file containing styles

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

But `IntelliSense` tells me that

> a value of type 'Style' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary
>   of type 'Resource Dictionary'.

So what is the correct way to start such a xaml file?

Comment: Are the WPF dlls referenced properly in your project?

Comment: @TimPohlmann  I'd thought that they were, but I'd missed a reference to WindowsBase.  I remember reading somewhere that when working with wpf one's better off starting with a wpf application template rather than a class library template.  I'd stupidly done the latter, added the presentation references but not the rest.  Doh!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Hey what you can do is is to add this file in a **Resource** , to use this file you can add the file reference in the **App.XAML** .

So basically you create a style , add it into the resource dictionary(.resx) file then you go to the App.Xaml and then you add the reference of the stylesheet as follow

```
    <Application x:Class="DualScreenSampleApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: You've missed the point of the question, What you suggest is my eventual aim, and yes I know I can do that.  What I want is a separate project containing various files that hold styles data templates etc.  My question is how does one commence the xaml mark-up in a file that will for example contain style definitions as illustrated in my question above.  The question / answer to which I referred in my question points out how to do the merging, I'm specifically after how to start individual files containing stle and template definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've got (I'd just shortened it for that sake of brevity in the question) and that is giving me the error I mentioned.

Comment: put the complete code in a separate XAML file and then hook up it into APP.XAML then in the xaml you can refer it

Comment: @DomSinclair Weird. I have a separate file for all my styles in one of my projects and when I removed the `xmlns:x...` line I got the same IntelliSense error as you. So I figured this would solve your problem. I guess something else is missing then.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a repository for styles and want to use `Styles` in all projects of your solution, I suggest you to read further.

You can create new project in your solution to keep Resources. To do it:

1. You can add to your solution `WpfControlLibrary1` and call it, for example, `YourProject.Resources`.
2. Create folder `Themes`
3. Create different xaml files in `Themes folder for each group of resources (like Generic.WPF.xaml for standard WPF controls' styles, Generic.Brushes.xaml for brushes etc.)
4. Create file `Themes\Generic.xaml` (exactly with this name, it will add huge benefits in the future) with content like:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.Brushes.xaml"/>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.WPF.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
5. Now you can add those resources to any project of your solution (you have separate project for it, right?) by adding reference to `YourApplication.Resources` to that project and adding to your view's xaml:

   ```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourApplication.Resources;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <!-- Put your not shared resource here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
   ```