# Styling project in visual studio solution (WPF XAML)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles, visual-studio-2017

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249492/how-to-organize-resources-styles-in-a-complex-wpf-scenario) and Marc's answer, I find this solution perfect, but I have trouble organizing my solution to make it functional.

How can I create a styling project that contains only XAML and reference to sub XAML, and how can I use it elsewhere in my solution? What is the visual studio project used by Marc in his answer to create the styling project?

Thank you,
B

Comment: Use Microsoft Blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a **WPF User Control Library** in Visual Studio and add `ResourceDictionary` items where you define your XAML resources to it.

You then add a reference to this WPF User Control Library from your **WPF Application** project (Project->Add Reference in Visual Studio) and merge the resource dictionaries that are defined in the library in the `App.xaml` of your application:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfUserControlLibrary1;component/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Replace "WpfUserControlLibrary1" with the name of the WPF User Control Library and "Dictionary1" with the name of the `ResourceDictionary` that you added to this project.

Comment: Thank you mm8, that's what I was looking for